# Inserting draggable divs on page load not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically insert draggable divs. Currently I am trying to insert on page load. I will change this to a button later. Nothing gets inserted into my container on page load and i dont understand why?

Edit: I fixed the typo as someone else pointed out and the div is inserted onto the page, but the div is still not draggable and i dont understand why?

```
//this makes elements with the draggable class draggable
 <script>
    $( function() {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    } );
//this inserts a draggable div on page load, will conert this to a button 
//call function later once i get inserting draggable divs working
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Container').append($("<div class='draggable'> This should be draggable</div>"));
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Putting divs inside this Container --->
    <div id="Container" style="border:solid; width:500px; height:500px;">
    </div>
```

Comment: you have a typo,change  `$('.Container')` to `$('#Container')`

Comment: Thanks! Cant believe i didnt see that.... Although i still have the issue that the element that was just created is still not draggable. Its static on the page and my mouse does not change when i hover over it like it should when hovering over text. Any idea why this dynamically created div wont move?

Comment: you need to initiate the plugin **after** the append

Comment: Ok, I have reversed the order. I now have the document.ready function with the append code before the function with $( ".draggable" ).draggable();. It still doesnt work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate the plugin **after** each append

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Container').append("<div class='draggable'> This should be draggable</div>");
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });
```